# Protractor closing current tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a non-angular page where I need to click on 2 links. When clicking on one of the link that automatically opens in a new tab. Now I switch to new tab and set the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` because the newly opened tab is a angular window; and call one of my test. Once verified. I want to close the current tab and go back to the non-angular page to click on link #2 which would again open in a new tab. I tried `window.close` but i am getting window is undefined. I used browser.window and even that is not working. Please advise

```
element(by.id('trMyUrl'));
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
             var secondWindowHandle = handles[1];
             var firstWindowHandle = handles[0];
    browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle).then(function () { //the focus moves on new tab\
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;    
    empLogin.test();
    window(secondWindowHandle).close()
    // window.close()
    // browser.close()
    // browser.window.close()

     })
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close your second window that is currently focused on and then `switchTo()` previous tab first to perform operations on it. Here's how -

```
browser.switchTo().window(secondWindowHandle)
.then(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;    
    empLogin.test();
}).then(function(){
    browser.close(); //close the current browser
}).then(function(){
    browser.switchTo().window(firstWindowHandle) //Switch to previous tab
    .then(function(){
        //Perform your operations on the first tab
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code is working to close the current tab but it closes without executing the tests for empLogin.test(). When I comment out the firstwindowhandle code and keep the browser.close code as it is and then run my test, I get no such window exits , target window already closed message. Please advise.

Comment: You are getting the issue because `browser.close()` is executing even before the `empLogin.test()` completes. To handle this, try returning a promise from the `empLogin.test()` and then use that promise to add your `browser.close()` function. Or chain the promise which i have updated in the answer. Also you need to switch to the firstWindowHandle as protractor wouldn't know where it is supposed to execute the tests. Thanks