# Protractor test fails for redirected urls that are written with target='_blank_'

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

```
fit('try google',async ()=>{    
        let logo = $('.logo')
        await logo.click();
        expect(await browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('https://www.google.com/');

    });

<div class="logo">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">google</a>
        </div>
```

Error

Expected 'http://localhost/thunfisch/home.aspx' to match 'https://www.google.com/'.

It works when target is not _blank. It looks pretty straight forward but i could not manage to get it worked. Thanks

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Kacper ok i have added the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target="_blank"` opens the link in a new tab.

You may still be on the first tab, but the test looks for google.com.

You should switch to last tab before assertion. See the documentation:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.switchTo

You can also take a look on example usage here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515194/6331748

**Edit:**
In non async way it looks like:

```
return.browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((availableTabs) => {
    return browser.switchTo().window(availableTabs[availableTabs.length - 1]);
});
```

voilà!

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: `getAllWindowHandles` returns `promise.Promise<string[]>` and `switchTo()` `TargetLocator`. It switches to last opened tab.